# Postgres - get LEAST of 2 COUNTs

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I would like to find the smallest of 2 table sizes like this:

```
create function least_func() returns void as $$
declare
    result INT;
begin

    select least(
               select count(*) from my_table,
               select count(*) from my_other_table) into result;

end $$ language plpgsql;
```

This does not compile:

`syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 7:                select count(*) from my_table,`

What's the problem with this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around your select statements.

```
select least(
   (select count(*) from my_table),
   (select count(*) from my_other_table)) into result;
```